# Make this data cleaning loop more Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am cleaning some human-classified data with Python 2.7, mainly using pandas, but using `numpy.isreal()` to check for floating-point numbers, because some people apparently entered floating-point numbers in fields like `'background_color'`.

Anyway, I'm posting an example of what it would look like for one color with my current setup, which works, but it just doesn't look very Python. By the end of the loops, `blues` is a list of all the indexes where `background_color` was case insensitive `'BLUE'`:

```
blueShapes=[]
for i in range(imageData.shape[0]):
    if not (np.isreal(imageData.loc[i,'background_color'])):
        if imageData.loc[i,'background_color'].upper()=='BLUE':
            blueShapes.append(i)
```

It seems like I could use the map function to make this more [Pythonic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pythonic#Adjective) and prettier. Like I said, it functions as intended, but it just seems too...C or Java for it to be written in Python.

Comment: `count = len(blueShapes)` should save you some `chars`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new column with upper cases:

```
imageData['background_color_2'] = map(lambda x: x.upper(), imageData['background_color'].astype(str))

subset = imageData[imageData['background_color_2']=='BLUE']
```

For the count:

```
len(subset['background_color'])
```

Comment: You sure I won;t run into an error when i call `.astype(str)` on a string object?

Comment: Guess not, it threw an exception when i tried to use that without `lambda`.

Comment: `.astype(str)` just convert `float` or `integer` to ` string` and keep string as string. the error you would get is if you try to x.upper() something that is not a string in the first place. since you pass a series that was all converted to string you should be fine, as an example it will treat a float value of 2.1 as a string '2.1'.  you can accept the answer after a while even if you don't have rep. glad it helped.

Comment: Also, is there a way to extract the indicies of the subset in the original data frame? I will eventually have to go through and manually label all the leftover values that are mislabeled. I suppose i could use some or statements to just generate a subset that is not any of the colors.

Comment: `subset.index` will return the `index` or as you call it the indices

Answer (score 0):

You can define a lambda function that returns the index of rows with a specific string value

```
getRowIndexWithStringColor = lambda df, color: [i for i in range(df.shape[0]) if (not np.isreal(df.loc[i,'background_color'])) and df.loc[i,'background_color'].upper()==color)]
rowIndexWithBlue = getRowIndexWithStringColor(imageData, 'BLUE')
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you are looping in [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29), you are doing it wrong.

It should look something like this (though it is untested, so you need to adapt it!):

```
strings = (~imageData.background_color.apply(np.isreal))
blue = (imageData.background_color.str.upper()=="BLUE")
blueshapes = imageData[strings & blue].index
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a minor adaptation to [Steven G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206618/make-this-data-cleaning-loop-more-python/40206651#40206651), and I have all of this backed up in a master *.csv* file, so I had no qualms with just overwriting the `background_color` column with its string equivalent. Any non-string entries are invalid anyway, but they are not alone, so I will find them later as leftover indexes after I concatenate the indexes of all the colors. Each list will be extracted as follows:

```
image_data['background_color']=map(lambda x: x.upper(), image_data['background_color'].astype(str))

blueShapes=image_data[image_data['background_color']=='BLUE'].index
```

### More idiomatic pandas approach

```py
image_data['background_color'] = image_data['background_data']
.astype(str))
.apply(lambda x: x.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would turn it into a function and return an array. See, for example, *[Zen of Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python)*.

I am giving you a quick reference: [Python list/dict/set over map/filter](https://github.com/amontalenti/elements-of-python-style#prefer-listdictset-comprehensions-over-mapfilter).

It is better readability and cleaner code.

```
def colorShapes(color):
    return [i
             for i in range(imageData.shape[0])
             if not(np.isreal(imageData.loc[i, 'background_color'].upper() == color 
             and imageData.loc[i, 'background_color'].upper() == color]
```